# WinAPI. Не перерисовывается WM_PAINT

Tags: winapi

В окне должен постоянно обновляться текст. При dcc = GetDC(hWnd) - текст моргает, но перерисовывается, а если использовать dcc = BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps) и EndPaint(hWnd, &ps) то не перерисовывается пока не развернуть  окно (не произойдет какое то событие), только тогда текст перерисуется с новыми параметрами. В чем проблема?

```
case WM_PAINT: {

        //dcc = BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);

        dcc = GetDC(hWnd);
        SetBkMode(dcc, OPAQUE);
        SetTextColor(dcc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        SetScrollRange(hWnd, SB_VERT, 0, math::countline, true);

        //hd = "All Lines :" + std::to_string(math::countline) + '\n' + '\n' + '\n';
        //copy(hd.begin(), hd.end(), tchars);
        //TextOut(dcc, 5, 10, tchars, hd.length());

        //step = math::countline / 50;
        //if (step < 1)step = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {

            if ((i + yPos)<math::countline)
            {
                a = "a:(" + std::to_string(math::vectorline[i+yPos].a) + "); ";
                k = "k:(" + std::to_string(math::vectorline[i + yPos].k) + "); ";
                b = "b:(" + std::to_string(math::vectorline[i + yPos].b) + "); ";

                x11 = std::to_string(math::vectorline[i + yPos].x1);
                y11 = std::to_string(math::vectorline[i + yPos].y1);
                x2 = std::to_string(math::vectorline[i + yPos].x2);
                y2 = std::to_string(math::vectorline[i + yPos].y2);
                n = std::to_string(i + yPos);
                hd = ' ' + n + " Line: A(" + x11 + "," + y11 + ") B(" + x2 + "," + y2 + ") ;" + "ScanLine : " + a + k + b + '\n' + '\n';

                copy(hd.begin(), hd.end(), tchars);
                TextOut(dcc, 10, 20 * i, tchars, hd.length());
            }
        }



        //EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd,dcc);



        break; }
```

Comment: *"не перерисовывается пока не развернуть окно (не произойдет какое то событие)"* - правильно, вам надо как раз инвалидировать окно в ответ на это самое событие. если необходимо перерисовывать постоянно, то заведите таймер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeginPaint` устанавливает область отсечения, исключающую действительные (не требующие перерисовки) части окна. Раз с окном не происходит никаких событий и никакая его чать не объявляется недействительной (с помощью [InvalidateRect](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) или [InvalidateRgn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidatergn)), то вся его поверхность остаётся действительной и соответственно не перерисовывается.